# Why doesn't intermediate value property of measures contradict additivity?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've reasoned myself into a contradiction and I can't see where I've gone wrong.

A finite measure $m$ on $(X, \mathcal{B})$ assigns positive measure to at most countably many disjoint measurable sets. If $m$ is non-atomic and non-zero, then for some measurable set $A$ with $m(A) > 0$ and all $0 \leq r \leq m(A)$, there exists a measurable $B_r \subset A$ with $m(B_r)=r$.

Since there are uncountably many such $r$, there are uncountably many disjoint $C \subset A$ of the form $C = B_{r_1} - B_{r_2}$, $r_1 > r_2$, and each $C$ has positive measure. Contradiction.

I think what's wrong is " there are uncountably many disjoint $C \subset A$ of the form...", but I can't prove why it's false.

Comment: I don't get the construction of the $C's$.  If $r_1>r_2$ is $B_{r_2}\subset B_{r_1}$?  If so , then $r_1>r_2>r_3\implies B_{r_1}-B_{r_2}\subset B_{r_1}-B_{r_3}$.

Comment: They are not pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming your sets $\{B_r\}$ are nested.

If you write $C_{a,b}$ to denote $B_{a} \setminus B_{b}$, you can see that two sets of the form $C_{a,b}$ and $C_{p,q}$ are disjoint if the intervals $(b,a)$ and $(q,p)$ are nonoverlapping. You can't come up with uncountably many nonoverlapping intervals, since each interval must contain a rational number unique to that interval.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something simple. This clears things up completely.